# Get keyword that my site searched for

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cookies, google-analytics

I am working on a website where I want to get keyword that my website was searched for on Google.

For example my website is for architect services, someone goes on Google and searches for "Architectural drawings" and gets my site in search and clicks.

I want to get that keyword stored as variable to serve dynamic content.

## EDIT

Looking at the answers I think i did not make myself clear.

I am signed up with analytics and I get reports on what keywords by site is being searched for.

What is currently want is When user clicks on google search result to visit my page, i want to use the keyword in order to deliver dynamic content on my page. so if user searched for "Architectural Drafting" and click on my link on search result, i want to deliver content related to architectural drafting and if keyword id "Architectural Design" then content may differ, so i need to get keyword stored as variable when visitor is on my page.

Is that possible?

## EDIT 2

I got answer that this is not possible but somehow i came along a plugin that claims under "What The Visitor Wants to Learn From Your Website SPECIFICALLY" first point "by the keywords people are using to land on your website" check link [1]. if they can personalize on the keyword people used to land on my website, there must be some technique used if not cookies, i want to find that out.

[1] http://smartduu.com/content-personalization-plugin/

Regards
Manoj Soni

Comment: Signup and use Google Analytics would be the place to start

Comment: Google Analytic is the right way, but you can process on referrer link and check search parameter, please read this article :
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/get-the-referrer-url-site-url-from-google-search/74629/3

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign up [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none) to see what keyword searches on Google.

> Track your site's search performance with Google Search Console and
>   browse around for more webmaster resources.

Optionally you can sign up [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) and [links it up to Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en) so that you can access more advance data for keyword search.

> If you associate a Google Analytics property with a site in your
>   Search Console account, you’ll be able to see Search Console data in
>   your Google Analytics reports. You’ll also be able to access Google
>   Analytics reports directly from the Links to your site, and Sitelinks
>   pages in Search Console.

Comment: I think i did not explain myself very well, I am signed up with analytics and i get reports on what keywords by site is being searched for. What is currently want is When user clicks on google search result to visit my page, i want to use the keyword in order to deliver dynamic content on my page. so if user searched for "Architectural Drafting" and click on my link on search result, i want to deliver content related to architectural drafting and if keyword id "Architectural Design" then content may differ, so i need to get keyword stored as variable when visitor is on my page.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible, at least not for organic search. The keyword is not included in the request that redirects a user from the search results to your page.

If you use Google Adwords then you can ad [value track parameters](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en) with the search term dynamically filled in to your destination urls. This will work for paid traffic only.

Google Analytics will not help here (for the most part it does not include organic search keywords, either).

Google Search Console will give you info on organic search terms, but not in realtime and will not help for your use case.

Comment: somehow i came along a plugin that claims under "What The Visitor Wants to Learn From Your Website SPECIFICALLY" first point "by the keywords people are using to land on your website" check link [link](http://smartduu.com/content-personalization-plugin/). if they can personalize on the keyword people used to land on my website, there must be some technique used if not cookies, i want to find that out.

Comment: @ManojSoni, to claim to be able to do something and actually be able to do it are two different things. Google at least does not send the keyword in the referrer (and cookies are not relevant here, as a plugin cannot set cookies on a Google SERP the user has previously visited), so I would guess they can only see the keywords when it is included specifically in the URL.